# Where can I find a better version of markdown?

Tags: markdown

I'm using markdown from the repos on Ubuntu 19.10. This seems to be a quite old version:

```
>markdown -v

This is Markdown, version 1.0.1.
Copyright 2004 John Gruber
http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/
```

It doesn't support useful features such as "fenced" code blocks (line are concatenated as if if only kept the last of the opening backticks and the first of the closing backticks).

When I look for a [markdown man page on the web](https://linux.die.net/man/1/markdown) there is obviously a more recent (2008) and more complete version (many more options than in my local man page). Where can I find it? Is its source available somewhere? Searching for markdown on the web is near impossible since you get thousands of hits for markdown syntax cheatsheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [some](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=pell.chi.il.us&literal=1&perpkg=1) [clues](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/amd64/discount/filelist) that the newer package is named `discount`.

But fenced code blocks are an [Markdown extension](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/).

Also I can recommend to check at least:

1. [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/) editor, which is build on top of `python3-markdown`:

   `sudo apt install retext`
2. [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) to convert between many formats and Markdown variants:

   `sudo apt install pandoc`
3. [RStudio](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/) for creation of comprehensive dynamic [RMarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) documents

Comment: Much better. `discount` is what I was looking for. There are also side utilities (mk2html) that can replace some of my scripts.